# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list say, temp_list with following properties :

```
len(temp_list) = 9260  
temp_list[0].shape = (224,224,3)
```

Now, when I am converting into numpy array,

```
x = np.array(temp_list)
```

I am getting the error :

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: i guess we need to use np.flatten()

Comment: flatten will distort the shape of the array.

Comment: What shape do you want it to be in? You're trying to create a new array out of a list of 3D arrays, so the final array could be 3 or 4D. You may get somewhere with `np.dstack` (or `np.hstack` or `np.vstack`).

Comment: I checked already, all elements are 3D having shape (224,224,3)

Comment: Could you tell us the output of `sum([item.size for item in temp_list])`?

Comment: You are right one element has the shape (224,224,360)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

At least one item in your list is either not three dimensional, or its second or third dimension does not match the other elements. If only the first dimension does not match, the arrays are still matched, but as individual objects, no attempt is made to reconcile them into a new (four dimensional) array. Some examples are below:

That is, the offending element's `shape != (?, 224, 3)`,
or `ndim != 3` (with the `?` being non-negative integer).
That is what is giving you the error.

You'll need to fix that, to be able to turn your list into a four (or three) dimensional array.  Without context, it is impossible to say if you want to lose a dimension from the 3D items or add one to the 2D items (in the first case), or change the second or third dimension (in the second case).

---

Here's an example of the error:

```
>>> a = [np.zeros((224,224,3)), np.zeros((224,224,3)), np.zeros((224,224))]
>>> np.array(a)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)
```

or, different type of input, but the same error:

```
>>> a = [np.zeros((224,224,3)), np.zeros((224,224,3)), np.zeros((224,224,13))]
>>> np.array(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)
```

Alternatively, similar but with a different error message:

```
>>> a = [np.zeros((224,224,3)), np.zeros((224,224,3)), np.zeros((224,100,3))]
>>> np.array(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224)
```

But the following will work, albeit with different results than (presumably) intended:

```
>>> a = [np.zeros((224,224,3)), np.zeros((224,224,3)), np.zeros((10,224,3))]
>>> np.array(a)
# long output omitted
>>> newa = np.array(a)
>>> newa.shape
3  # oops
>>> newa.dtype
dtype('O')
>>> newa[0].shape
(224, 224, 3)
>>> newa[1].shape
(224, 224, 3)
>>> newa[2].shape
(10, 224, 3)
>>>
```

Comment: Okay so this answers what's causing the error but how to resolve it. I'm having the same issue but in my case I'm directly converting a raw-image to np.array using img_to_array(), tensorflow. Hence I don't have the privileged to convert it to .astype(object) as mentioned by @YinJie Gao below. T.I.A.

Answer (score 14):

Yea, Indeed @Evert answer is perfectly correct.
In addition, I'd like to add one more scenario that could encounter such an error.

```
>>> np.array([np.zeros((20,200)),np.zeros((20,200)),np.zeros((20,200))])
```

This will be perfectly fine. However, this leads to `ValueError`:

```
>>> np.array([np.zeros((20,200)),np.zeros((20,200)),np.zeros((20,201))])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,200) into shape (20)
```

The `numpy` arrays within the list must also be the same size.

Comment: Thanks for this additional information. My problem is the exactly as you mentioned, the inner ndarrays' shape is different.

Comment: Thanks for that addition, I stumbled over this exact issue. The funny thing is if you switch around the 20 and 200/201 in the second case, it works, which I find quite confusing. Numpy will not create a 3D array in that case but instead a 1D array containing 2D arrays. So totally different behaviour from a seemingly innocent change. A bit frustrating to be honest.

Answer (score 12):

You can covert `numpy.ndarray` to `object` using `astype(object)`

This will work:

```
>>> a = [np.zeros((224,224,3)).astype(object), np.zeros((224,224,3)).astype(object), np.zeros((224,224,13)).astype(object)]
```

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem because some of the images are grey scale images in my data set, so i solve my problem by doing this

```
    from PIL import Image
    img = Image.open('my_image.jpg').convert('RGB')
    # a line from my program
    positive_images_array = np.array([np.array(Image.open(img).convert('RGB').resize((150, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS)) for img in images_in_yes_directory])
```

Comment: I had a similar problem but decided to add an `if img.shape == (width, height, 3):` clause to my function that cut out any grayscale images. An alternative out there for other No0bs finding their way.

Answer (score 3):

@aravk33 's answer is absolutely correct.

I was going through the same problem. I had a data set of 2450 images. I just could not figure out why I was facing this issue.

Check the dimensions of all the images in your training data.

Add the following snippet while appending your image into your list:

```
if image.shape==(1,512,512):
    trainx.append(image)
```

Answer (score 3):

This method does **not** need to modify dtype or ravel your numpy array.

The core idea is:
1.initialize with one extra row.
2.change the list(which has one more row) to array
3.delete the extra row in the result array
e.g.

```
>>> a = [np.zeros((10,224)), np.zeros((10,))]
>>> np.array(a)
# this will raise error,
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,224) into shape (10)

# but below method works
>>> a = [np.zeros((11,224)), np.zeros((10,))]
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b[0] = np.delete(b[0],0,0)
>>> print(b.shape,b[0].shape,b[1].shape)
# print result:(2,) (10,224) (10,)
```

Indeed, it's not necessarily to add one more row, as long as you can escape from the gap stated in @aravk33 and @user707650 's answer and delete the extra item later, it will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was in my data set, Basically i was need to pre process on my data before further processing, because in my data set images are in random formats like RGB and grayscale, So dimensions mismatch.
I simply follow [Mudasir Habib's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63718532/17469198) answer.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('my_image.jpg').convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 1):

### SOLVED -
I got same arror :
X_test = np.array(X_test, )
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (50,50,3) into shape (50,50)

printed every images shape and got like this:

~

1708 : (50, 50, 3)

1709 : (50, 50)

1710 : (50, 50)

1711 : (50, 50, 3)

1712 : (50, 50, 3)

1713 : (50, 50, 3)

~

which means Mixed 1D and 3D datas after reading 2 different image folders and shuffling them

[img: first one is Grayscale and second one is Color image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Bk6.png)

Added cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE and problem is solved

Summary:
in image data which I wanted to convert into np array contained different dimensional images

-> checked image data

-> found out that there are 1D, and 3D images

-> made 3D images Grayscale(1D)

-> problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Numpy will auto-unify the array if it finds that there is <= 1 dimension different).

If you don't want to have a unified array (all elements are in the same shapes), you can try this workaround:

```py
x = np.emtpy(len(temp_list), dtype=object)
for i, arr in enumerate(temp_list):
    x[i] = arr
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @mudassir's Answer. If you have agumented your dataset, then its highly likely that you get this error. As in most of the augumentation, it automatically applies grayscale effect which is actually two-dimensional whereas the original pictures (RGB) are three-dimensional.
I myself was using roboflow's dataset that was already augumented and had the similar issue. I then removed the "graysclaing step" and still it gave the error. However, one i removed grayscale, hue and saturation, it worked like a charm. I would suggest you try that too.