# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (160,320,1) into shape (160,320)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I've images array which appends processed images one by one

```
tmp = image[:,:,1].reshape(160, 320, 1)
images.append(tmp)
```

After that I'm converting images to numpy array

```
X_train = np.array(images)
```

But, I'm getting

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (160,320,1)
>   into shape (160,320)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128,3) into shape (128,128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186313/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-128-128-3-into-shape-1)

Comment: Please, google it first and then ask a question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977463/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-224-224-3-into-shape-2

Comment: @Olia both of the links doesn't solve the problem