# Remove last elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've this numpy array:

```
array([ 0.49010508,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.09438115,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
   -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
   -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
   -1.        , -1.        ])
```

which is the first row of the 5D numpy array called `allSimilarity`. I have defined it with `np.full()` and the `fill_value` is -1. After computing, I would want to remove last unuseful `-1` value. So, I calculate the size difference, but when I use `np.delete()` or `np.resize()` or `allSimilarity[index1][index2][index3][index4] = allSimilarity[index1][index2][index3][index4][:diff].copy()` (where `diff` is the size difference between old size and new size) I got this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (55) into shape (67)
```

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: of course you can't remove it (and therefore resize it) if there are more dimensions in which rely data which would remain in the old shape. That's what the Error told you. Maybe give us more insights into the other data?

Comment: You cannot resize a single row in a ND array, if that is what you are trying to do. Of course you can resize all rows - but all of them must have the same size.

Comment: have a look on [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977463/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-224-224-3-into-shape-2)

Comment: So, the unique way to go ahead is to exclude the `-1` value when computing? Could I "mask" `-1` value before computing mean, or any other math operation?

Comment: Where does the `-1` come from?  Sounds like NaN (`np.nan`) was maybe more fitting.

Comment: Replaced `-1` values with `np.nan` values! `np.nan` values in math operations won't be including in computing?

Comment: Hi @FedericoCuozzo  What is the size of your array?

Comment: Any number being operated with `nan` will result in `nan`. `nan+100 = nan`, etc.

Comment: If I try to call `mean()` method on 2d array I got `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` error. If I try to call `nanmean()` method, I got `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nanmean'` error.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np

j = np.array([ 0.49010508,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.09438115,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
   -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
   -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
   -1.        , -1.        ])

j = j[j!=-1]
print j
```

**Result:**

```
[ 0.49010508  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.09438115  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
```

Comment: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (55) into shape (69)` because I've a 2D array.