# Adding new lines results in ValueError in numpy.asarray

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror, openmesh

Prior to adding the neighbor statements (that I commented with 'new'), everything worked just fine. Now, when using *numpy.asarray*, there is following error:

*ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3).*

I'm really confused as the new lines didn't change anything about the rotations-array.

```
def rre(mesh, rotations):
"""
Relative Rotation Encoding (RRE).
Return a compact representation of all relative face rotations.
"""
all_rel_rotations = neighbors = []
for f in mesh.faces():
    temp = [] # new
    for n in mesh.ff(f):
        rel_rotation = np.matmul(rotations[f.idx()], np.linalg.inv(rotations[n.idx()]))
        all_rel_rotations.append(rel_rotation)
        temp.append(n.idx()) # new
    neighbors.append(temp) # new
all_rel_rotations = np.asarray(all_rel_rotations)
neighbors = np.asarray(neighbors) # new
return all_rel_rotations, neighbors
```

Comment: could you please edit the code to also provide an example of input and output?

Comment: Print the value of `neighbors` before `neighbors = np.asarray(neighbors)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43977463/190597).

Comment: @unutbu: I don't think that it is that duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem is very likely the line:

```
all_rel_rotations = neighbors = []
```

In Python lists are mutables and `all_rel_rotations` and `neighbors` point to the same list, so if you do `all_rel_rotations.append(42)` you will see that `neighbors = [42, ]`

The line:

```
all_rel_rotations.append(rel_rotation)
```

appends a 2D array, while

```
neighbors.append(temp)
```

appends a 1D array (or the other way around) to the same list. Then:

```
all_rel_rotations = np.asarray(all_rel_rotations)
```

tries to convert to an array and get confused.

If you need to list do

```
all_rel_rotations = []
neighbors = []
```

Comment: This is an error that everyone starting with python does: one must learn the difference between mutables and non-mutables variables and how they are handled it the hard way :D.

Comment: Well, at least this particular one will never happen again. You probably saved me hours of searching and frustration :)

Comment: To save you hours in the future I suggest to learn to use the python debugger as soon as possible