# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (65536) into shape (256,256,1)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a gray scale image as an array with shape **(256,256,1)** and I want to flatten it to have shape ***(65536,)***.

I tried using reshape , flatten and ravel but nothing works.

I also looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977463/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-224-224-3-into-shape-2)

but I don't really understand the solution as I am a beginner in python.

How do I go about solving this?

**Edit:**

This is the line of code that makes the problem

```
image_width = image_height = 256
X[0] = np.reshape(X[0],(image_width*image_height))
```

Where X has the following shape: **(64, 256, 256, 1)**

dtype of array is **float32**

Comment: Exactly what statement produced the title error.  That's not a `reshape` message.

Comment: I just tried using reshape and It gave me the exact same error.

Comment: Can you include that line of code? and also the full error traceback?

Comment: just did Can you please check it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977463/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-224-224-3-into-shape-2)

Comment: Even if the `reshape` works, you can't put it back into the original array!  It's not the reshape that's producing the error.  It's the `x[0]=...` assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this doesn't work:

```
In [80]: x = np.ones((256,256,1))                                                                      
In [81]: x.reshape(65536,).reshape((256,256,1));
```

there must be something unusual about your array.  A fuller description of the array (not just shape, but also dtype), along with the code and full traceback might help.

===

You edit shows that you are doing more than `reshape`.  You are trying to put the reshaped (sub)array back into the orginal.

Add a dimension to `x`:

```
In [86]: x = np.ones((1,256,256,1))
```

reshape of a subarray still works:

```
In [88]: x[0].reshape(65536);
```

but trying to put that reshaped array back into `x` produces the error:

```
In [89]: x[0] = x[0].reshape(65536);                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-c488a5e4f450> in <module>
----> 1 x[0] = x[0].reshape(65536);

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (65536) into shape (256,256,1)
```

Like I wrote, `reshape` does not produce this error; it's the assignment that does.

Comment: I tried this it gives me the same shape (256,256,1).