# Converting a 3-D image list to np.array throws ValueError

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras

I was working on **Sequential model** for **plant disease detection problem**.
Initially I used an `image_list=[]` and converted images to array using `img_to_array(image)` 
My next step was to use `test_train_split` but before that I need to convert this list to array hence I used this:
`im_list=np.array(image_list,dtype=np.float16)/255.0`
 But this line throws "*ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (64,64,3) into shape (64,64)*." 
I understand it's an image list but generally it should convert a 3-D list to array as I tried with a sample list which it converted successfully. I don't get why this wouldn't work!!
**::[UPDATE]::**
PS: If the answers posted on the similar post doesn't help your issue. [ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977463/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-224-224-3-into-shape-2)

and if you cannot modify the dimensions or implement .astype() as stated in that post!!. Try using the below function:

```
if len(img.shape)>2 and img.shape[2]==4:
        img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
```

This generally happens when there's a 'PNG' image in the dataset. 
*Sample Trial*:

```
li=np.random.rand(10,10,2)
lii=np.array(li,dtype=np.float16)
```

**Variable Explorer:**

[image]

**Terminal Window:**
[image]

Comment: What do you mean, "you tried the answers"?  The link answers tell us that one or more of your images has a different shape from the others.   Did you identify that array?  It's likely that you have a mix of color and b/w images.

Comment: @hpaulj I wrote a small snippet that checks if ndim(arr)==3, if not, it should print the image name and exit the program. But as a matter of fact the program ran completely without any trouble for some reason. And again got stuck at ValueError. Hence I came back to update this section.

Comment: A (64,64,1) would also give problems.  The arrays in the list differ in the 3rd dimension.  Examine `shape` for all those arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks, I did a arr.shape check and it comes out that few images have 4 channels somehow!! And I rechecked that this problem was already answered in that post. I feel so foolish rn. I'll fix up this post later on.