# Numpy matrix broadcasting issues

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

`data` is a 1256x277 matrix

`np.array_split(ary=data, indices_or_sections=10, axis=1)` gives us a list of 1256x28 data

But when I do:

```
sub_data_ndarray = np.array(object=np.array_split(ary=data, indices_or_sections=10, axis=1))
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1256,28) into
> shape (1256)

?

Comment: Check that all the arrays produced by `np.array_splt` have the same shape.

Comment: @hpaulj  The result is seven 1256x28 matrix and three 1256x27 matrix.

Comment: Then you can't reassemble them into one 3d array.

Comment: @hpaulj  hmmm but I'm not trying to. I want to convert the resulting list [sub_data, sub_data, sub_data] into a ndarray so I can use ndarray selection operations. And those sub_data just happens to be a matrix.

Comment: What kind of `ndarray selection operations` do you have in mind?  At best you can make an object dtype array.  I could show you how to do that, but ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62994636/901925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `np.stack`:

```py
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
C = np.stack((A, B))
```

Comment: `np.array((A,B))` works with your lists just as well.  I expect `stack` will have problems with the OP's list as well, though it will give a different (and possibly clearer) error message.