# Numpy wrongly converts Networkx graphs to array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, networkx

I got an issue when trying to cast a networkx graph list into a Numpy array.
It appears that when all graphs of the list have the same number of nodes, Numpy automatically converts input graphs into arrays and the result is not what I expect.

Here is a small reproduction script:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

g1 = nx.DiGraph([(1, 2), (2, 3)])
g2 = nx.DiGraph([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)])
g3 = nx.DiGraph([(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3)])

ok_numpy = np.array([g1, g2], dtype=object)
ko_numpy = np.array([g1, g3], dtype=object)

>> ok_numpy = [<networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at ...>, <networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at ...>]
>> ko_numpy = [[1 2 3], [1 2 3]] <-- Objects are not DiGraph() anymore, edges info is lost, dimension is 2 instead of 1
```

If anybody knows a solution so that `ko_numpy` could behave the same way `ok_numpy` does, it would be perfect.

Comment: Can't you leave it as a list?  What benefit is there to making an array?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug-feature of `numpy`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62997901/10693596). The current solution is to create an empty array and assign specific elements to it:

```py
ko_numpy2 = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
ko_numpy2[:] = [g1, g3]
```

Not ideal, but workable.