# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512) into shape (512,512,1)

Tags: tensorflow, opencv

I've tried modifying the code with the pre_process function and the color_mode but each time a different error pops up.

```
def pre_process(img):
    ret, mask = cv2. threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
    return mask_inv

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, vertical_flip=True,preprocessing_function=pre_process)
test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, vertical_flip=True,preprocessing_function=pre_process)

train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory(path,
                                          target_size=(512,512),
                                          batch_size = 32,
                                          class_mode = 'binary',
                                          color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                          shuffle = True
                                          )
                                         
test_dataset = test.flow_from_directory(path,
                                          target_size=(512,512),
                                          batch_size =32,
                                          class_mode = 'binary',
                                          color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                          shuffle = True
                                          )
```

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512) into shape
(512,512,1)..... It's what i get from the above code.

However, if i used the pre_process method below, there is no error, but my loss is always NAN while training.

```
def pre_process(img):
    ret, mask = cv2. threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
    img_expanded = tf.expand_dims(mask_inv, 2)
    return img_expanded
```

Comment: it would be helpful to know what errors those are

Comment: i get the value error, but if i use tf.expand_dims(img_tensor, 2), i get another error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977463/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-224-224-3-into-shape-2)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help solve the problem at hand

Comment: If you could let us know how you are defining and compiling your model to find out cause of NaN loss while training.