# Python: Why can't I add a 3x1 array to one column of a 3x100 array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Variable `a` has the shape (3,1) and variable `b` has the shape (3,100). Now, I want to add variable `a` to just one column of variable `b`, meaning:

```
x[:,ii] = a + b[:,ii]
```

However, I get this message:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3,)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977463/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-224-224-3-into-shape-2)

Comment: By the rules of broadcasting `b[:,11]` is expanded from (3,) to (1,3).  Add that to a (3,1) and we get a (3,3).  The error comes from trying to put that into a (3,) slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`numpy.ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) Because `a.shape` is `(3,1)` and you need `(3,)`.

```
x[:,ii] = a.ravel() + b[:,ii]


# Or By thanks `@Raphael` we can use `np.squeeze()`
# x[:,ii] = a.squeeze() + b[:,ii]
```

Comment: `a.squeeze()` might be better here for readability

Comment: @Raphael, Thanks you are right. I add to my answer

Answer (score -1):

because the shape is 3 X 1 and 3x100, to multiply the column of first matrix and row of second matrix should be same(for eg. it would work it the matrix's are 3x1 X 1x100)

Comment: The question is about matrix "addition"--not multiplication.